# Log4j.xml, same package, different level goes to different appender

Tags: xml, log4j

Assume I have two appenders CONSOLE and FILE. For the package "my.package", I want WARN+ level logs go to FILE and INFO+ level logs go to CONSOLE.

The following code only send INFO+ level logs to CONSOLE, nothing goes to FILE:

```
<category name="my.package">
    <priority value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</category>
<category name="my.package" additivity="false">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</category>
```

The following code will cause error like this:

log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [FILE].

```
<category name="my.package">
    <priority value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</category>
<category name="my.package">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</category>
```

How to send WARN+ level logs to FILE and INFO+ level logs to CONSOLE?